# is there a way to send a message from server to one client only in Java sockets?

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm trying to build a server and client app. The client will send login data (email and password) to the server. then the server will respond to the client whether the login data is correct or not. the problem is I want the server to respond only to the client that has sent the login data only. Note that I want to keep the class methods generic so that I can use them on GUI (Javafx) controller classes. how can I achieve this?

```java
public class ServerConnector extends Thread{

    public static final int PORT_NO = 5005;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    /**
     * Starts the server
     */
    public void startServer() {
       this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       Socket clientSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NO);
            while (true) {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

```java
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private DataInputStream dis;
    private PrintStream ps;
    private Socket clientSocket;


    public static Vector<ClientHandler> clientThreads = new Vector<ClientHandler>();

    public ClientHandler(Socket s) {
        try {         
            this.clientSocket = s;
            dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientThreads.add(this);
            start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            try {
                String str = dis.readLine();
                if(str.equals("JavaTODO_ClientFINISH"))
                {
                    System.out.println("JavaTODO_ClientFINISH");
                    clientThreads.remove(this);
                    this.stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

    /**
     * sends message to all clients connected to the server
     *
     * @param msg to be sent
     */
    public static void sendToAll(String msg) {
        for (ClientHandler ch : clientThreads) {
            ch.ps.println(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * sends message to one client
     *
     * @param msg to be sent to one client
     */
    public void sendToOneClient(String msg,int index) {     
            ps.println(msg);
            //clientThreads.get(index).ps.println(msg);
            //psStatic.println(msg);    
    }

    /**
     * close the open connection and release resources
     */
    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            dis.close();
            ps.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to respond to the specific requests (not for arbitrary text string) the sockets look like too low-level approach and presumably you are inventing a bicycle.
 And of course it's not secure to send a password through unsecured connection.

For this task I would consider RMI connection, since server and clients are both java, so you can transparently invoke specific java function on server.

Comment: @edwgiz this is not for a production project. and these methods won't always send login data. I have to do it using Socket only.

Comment: A couple of confusions with your code: **1.** Where is ```sendToOneClient()``` being called? That will decide how it is being used. If the call happens synchronously after receiving message from the client, this code should work. However, you are not calling it there. **2.** The code seems to be using deprecated methods. Which Java version is this on?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a type of cookie. A cookie is nothing more than a string that's sent along with a request.

```
 cookie=login_id:33384adeg73eg344;
```

Only when people have successfully logged in, the cookie id is given to them, and they send it back along on every subsequent request that's sent to the server to authenticate them.

A small illustration of how it would work.

[image: flowchart]

If you take a look at normal http headers you see a lot of meta data that's useful to servers to know how to handle the data, what data the requester expects/accepts, in what language, what the cookies are, etc.. You could consider writing a simple thing like this in your socket handler, to be able to translate what the client "wants"

```
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 489
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: id=foobar
origin: https://stackoverflow.com
```

But I suggest you look into security as well. These transmissions are all easily intercepted by network sniffers and the like, and can be spoofed. Ideally you'd use a secure network transport library that supports secure connections, at least [SSLServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html) if you insist on writing your own implementation.